# How can I implement Paypal Chained Payment with PHP

Tags: paypal

I am quite new to Paypal Payment gateway although I have implemented the conventional paypal gateway API previously. But I'm kind of confused as to how to implement Paypal chained payment as I have been to paypal documentation site and I seem to be overwhelmed with a whole load of info. Any link or tutorial as to how I can implement this in a straightforward manner will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to second Sumit Neema's answer.

**EDIT** Unfortunately, it seems paypal-labs is out of commission. What a shame.
Here's an updated link to the Adaptive Payments PHP sample code:

https://github.com/paypal/codesamples-php/tree/master/AdaptivePayments/sample/code

The thing that trips most people up, is how money flows in a chained payment.

On a chained payment you will have one primary receiver, who is the one that the customer sees, and upt to five secondary receivers (Invisible to the paying customer).

initially 100% of the money will move from the buyer to the primary receiver, and then, paypal will subtract from the primary whatever portion belongs to the secondary receiver(s).

For example,  a $100 payment needs to be split 70/30 between primary and secondary.

Initially $100 will be in the primary receiver's account.  Paypal will then take $30, and move it to the secondary.

The end result? Primary has $70,  secondary has $30.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Lenny, your solution is nice..Thanks. But, now the above mentioned link is not available. Please send if you find...thanks..

Comment: @Lenny Markus the above mentioned link is not available . Is there any other way to do it.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

These Are some of the useful links .Hope it can help you

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APIntro

https://www.x.com/authentication-0

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-code-samples

Checkout This Link it has the full code sample and step by step approch to implement chaining payments in paypal in php or whaetver language you need.I know one thing that this code samples are very usefull ,you just need to place the API key and the paypal email to be paid or being paid and rest will be done effortlessly

check this link

https://www.paypal-labs.com/integrationwizard/adaptive/

Comment: thanks @SumitNeema. I have been through those links previously although they have been informative ,I still find them quite complex for a beginner like myself. I found a tutorial that actually explains what am trying to achieve only it was written in Python while i use php.this is the link- http://blog.widenhome.com/2012/01/27/paypal-adaptive-payments-api-integration-a-step-by-step-tutorial/#comment-104. so i need guidance to achieve what was done in this tutorial using php.any help will be appreciated

Comment: ok i will try to find and do whatever i can and will post here if i got any thing